# 1 Using the substitution method for solving recurrences 1

Tags: python, list

```
F(x,y)=3x+10y
```

I want to show all result of `f(x,y)` for x={0,1…,5} and y={0,1,…..,8} in python
i tried:

```
from math import *
def f(x,y):
    x in rang(5)
    y in rang(8)
    return (3*x)+(10*y)

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: One suggestion, NEVER get into the habit of using import * if you want to do some serious programming in future. This clutters your namespace.

Comment: It looks to me like a bad case of indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have the idea of how a function works mixed up. You should be looping outside the `f(x,y)` function and passing in `x` and `y`.

I believe that this is what you want:

```
from math import *

def f(x, y):
    return (3 * x) + (10 * y)

for x in range(5):
    for y in range(8):
        print "f(%d, %d) = %d" % (x, y, f(x, y))
```

Comment: print ("f(%d, %d) = %d" % (x, y, f(x, y))) is what i want sir

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the results in a list like this and then return at the end of the loops like this

```
def f(x,y):
    result = []
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            result.append((3*i)+(10*j))
    return result

print f(5, 8)
```

Or you can use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to shorten the loop secion like this

```
def f(x,y):
    return [(3*i)+(10*j) for i in range(x) for j in range(y)]
```